# Count Distinct Values in column , Return Zero if not found On Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my Table:

[image: This is my table]

and I am running this query,

```
SELECT fruits,COUNT(*) as count FROM meva where owner = 'bill' GROUP BY fruits ORDER BY count
```

and i am getting result as

[image]

Is it possible to get the other fruits items as 0 if not matched with owner like this,

```
Fruit   | count
Apple   ,   2
Mango   ,   0
Banana  ,   0
Strawberry ,0
Appricot,   0
Alfonso ,   0
```

A little modification in my query is most appreciated. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SUM()` and `CASE`

```
SELECT  fruits, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN owner = 'bill' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `count `
FROM     meva 
GROUP BY fruits 
ORDER BY fruits
```

or by using `IF` (*in `MySQL` only*)

```
SELECT  fruits, 
        SUM(IF(owner = 'bill',1,0)) as `count `
FROM     meva 
GROUP BY fruits 
ORDER BY fruits
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*CASE and IF*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c124/1)

Comment: Just `SUM(owner = 'bill')` will suffice in MySQL :)

Comment: @Jack good one :D really good one! I guess in my logic that's what is working regardless of `coalesce` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a nice answer up there. You can also try this!

```
SELECT  fruits, 
        SUM(Coalesce(owner='bill',0)) as counts
FROM     meva 
GROUP BY fruits 
ORDER BY fruits
;
```

Comment: @Zan let me know how this goes as well :) should work in MYSQL and SQL Server as well.